# Set Cloud Firestore rules to access same admin account from staff account

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I created an ERP Flutter app, with multiple "shops", where Admins account can add staff members and this staff can manage some Firebase collections on their behalf.
So, the idea is that staff should login the same account of the Admin, or at least, read and write the same collections.

The problem I am facing is that "users" collection has multiple "Admin". Each Admin assigned to a shop. I need help in setting up the Firestore rules to allow only "staff ID" included in "staff" array from that particular Shop/Admin document to read and write permission.

As the screenshot below:

- each Admin has a "staff" array with staff ID;
- staff are also saved inside the users collection;
- staff needs to access the "Category" and "InventoryCat" collections.

[image]

Maybe I am doing this wrong, and I need to set "Category" and "InventoryCat" as independent collections not released to the Admin, and share same "reference" across Admin and staff of the same shop?

**Stream to call collection "categories:**

```
 StreamBuilder(
        stream: _services.userRef.doc(_services.getUserID()).collection(_collectionName).orderBy('name').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following rules should do the trick: We check if the Id of the user is within the `staff` array **OR** if the user's ID is the parent collection ID (i.e. the user is the Admin himself):

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{userId}/Categories/{catId} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null && (request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId)).data.staff || request.auth.uid == userId);
      allow write: ...
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the above rule is only for the `Categories` subcollections, you need to declare the same one for `InventoryCat` and `daily_production` subcollections.

Comment: I get a "Null check operator used on a null value", mostly because of the rules. just to understand better, "get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId)).data.staff" is mapping over all users docs right? the "userId" is not referred to the current user logged in?

Comment: sorry, I can log in, but I don't see the categories. it returns empty page and I cannot see staff profile data either.

Comment: Can you try with `allow read: request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId)).data.staff || request.auth.uid == userId;` (removing the first check).

Comment: And to answer your question `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId))` points to ONE document, the parent of the Categories document you try to read. ALSO, can you put in your question the code that you use to fetch the Categories document. (Note also that the rule in my answer is only for Categories, you need to declare the same one for `InventoryCat` and `daily_production` sub collections)

Comment: PS: See the doc on ["Access other documents in Security Rules"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents)

Comment: yes, I already set the rules for others collections too.
I just noticed my log and it prints this when I log in, with 14 different UID, but none of the UID printed, match my users UID.
[Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(users/llDQZQ1afu4E5FJ50w3y order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254727/discussion-between-giovanni-and-renaud-tarnec).

Comment: You are listening to the `users` collection not to the `Categories`(sub)collection. You want to read documents into the `Categories`(sub)collection so you need to point to the exact path of this collection not to its parent